# finding a smaller number than a given number in a very large array without linear search

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

I want to find last occurrence of a number smaller or equal than a given number. Since the integer vector is very very large, O(n) is not that efficient.

I divided the vector into two parts and parallel searched.

Lets understand with an example:-

```
vector <int> arr = {1, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 5, 7, 4 ,6};
```

I want to find last occurence of a number smaller or equal to say 2, so I divided the array into two:

```
{1, 8, 7, 1, 2} and {9, 5, 7, 4, 6}
```

and started searching from end in both arrays.

As we can see, a number smaller or equal to 2 is at position 5 (index 4) but it could have been at any position greater than 5 so we still have to search second array entirely since our objective is to find the element at maximum index.

I want to ask if there is any stl function to find such number lesser than 2 in second array so that I do not have search the second array entirely.

Can I use std::find to find a number smaller than 2 in the second array?

EDIT: a number smaller or equal to 2 is at position 5 (index 4) but it could have been at any position greater than 5, so we stop at position 5 in the first array but continue searching second array. Suppose we get element 1 at position 7(index 6), since 7 > 5 so we just return position 7 and program ends. This saved us from searching the first array entirely.

Comment: if the vectors are not sorted no chance.binary search could be used which needs vector to be sorted

Comment: You are essentially asking "How can I check every item in array without checking each item in array".

Comment: There are stl like lower_bound and upper_bound as well as find_last_of  but all needs vector to be sorted

Comment: Unfortunately, this vector can not be sorted.

Comment: you can search in reverse but worst case it will be O(n)..if the only element equal or less is the first element

Comment: @VTT I did not really mean that. In that example, 2 is at position 5 so we stop at position 5 in the first array but still checking the second array for an element less than 2. I'm sorry if you did not understand, its probably my weak english.

Comment: Splitting array does not prevent search from being linear and does not eliminate need to check all the items in the worst case. Though it will become X times faster if those arrays are processed in X threads in parallel. If this is a practical question you can rephrase it to "how to make linear search faster?".

Comment: what's the use case? Could you avoid building the vector at all, or do the analysis while building the vector?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're essentially asking the impossible.   You have an unsorted array and want to find the last occurrence of in the array of a value that doesn't exceed some input value.   But you want to do that without examining all elements of the array.   If there array is unsorted, there is no way to do what you want without checking every element.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're starting with a vector, we are bound to inspect every element if we search from beginning to end.

However, if we search from end to beginning, we can stop as soon as the predicate is satisfied. This makes the algorithm worst-case O(N) and best-case O(1).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    auto arr = std::vector <int>{ 1, 8, 7, 1, 2, 9, 5, 7, 4 ,6 };

    auto less_than_three = [](auto&& x) { return x < 3; };

    auto rpos = std::find_if(rbegin(arr), rend(arr), less_than_three);

    if (rpos == rend(arr))
    {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    }
    else
    {
        auto pos = prev(rpos.base());
        auto index = distance(begin(arr), pos);
        std::cout << "found at position " << index << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: And if the array is **really, really large** the search can be run in parallel (with C++17) by simply changing `std::find_if(...)` to `std::find_if(std::execution::par ...)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I was going to suggest this but I haven't been able to find an implementation of c++17 with a library that supports the `<execution>` header.

Comment: Trust me, it works. <g> I’ve implemented the parallel algorithms for the Dinkumware library. In fact, this code looks very much like one of the test cases that I wrote. It really is that simple; it just works. The key to the **original** question is, as you say, using a reverse iterator.

Comment: @PeteBecker Interesting. How does the Dinkumware implementation avoid pessimising the search in the case of, for example, the predicate passing half way through a chunk? When I was thinking about an implementation of this it occurred to me that either there has to be some atomic flagging in the loops, use of multiple small chunks, or just accepting that the search will take (N / threads) iterations.

Comment: Yes, you do multiple small chunks. That’s needed for load balancing, and it also supports short-circuiting when a chunk is found that has an element that satisfies the predicate. Done right (<g>) there’s virtually no overhead.

Comment: @RichardHodges lets say we divide the vector into 3 parts and search all of them at the same time, won't the complexity come down to O(n/3)? Its not the best but still better than O(n) but the problem is I am not able to implement it.